# How to query in Azure Devops for the date a specific state was set for a task

Tags: azure-devops

I am currently running a query that gets all the Tasks under a specific feature. Now all of these tasks are done for this feature, but I want to see when (the date) it was set in progress.

How can I achieve this in Azure Devops using custom queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you are looking for is the "Activated Date".  It should be set initially moving the task to "In Progress" and not updated again.  It will be cleared if the task is ever moved back to "To Do".

[image]